# How to get a value for a key in a string, when followed by another specific key=value set

Tags: python, regex

my code is like:

```
string = "title=abcd color=green title=efgh color=blue title=xyxyx color=yellow title=whatIwaht color=red title=xxxy red=anything title=xxxyyy color=red"
pattern = r'title=(.*?) color=red'
print re.compile(pattern).search(string).group(0)
```

and I got

```
"title=abcd color=green title=efgh color=blue title=xyxyx color=yellow title=whatIwaht color=red title=xxxy red=anything title=xxxyyy color=red"
```

But I want to find all the contents of "title"s immediately followed by "color=red"

Comment: What **do** you want the pattern to return?

Comment: "that is close to": you'll need to define this much clearer. Is one short word like "and" less separation than 10 spaces? Example: `title="a" color="white" and title="b" \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ color="black"`, what should match what? (I had to escape the spaces; just remove the backslashes mentally.)

Comment: I've altered the rather unparseable title to be more general (I assume the title still reflects what you intend to achiev).

Comment: Will spaces be the only delimiter between your the "title=atitle" and "color=acolor", or can there be e.g., periods, commas, semi-colons, tabs etc?

Comment: Unfotunately not, there are a lot of tags like "charactor ? & alph numeric "between them.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. There are only spaces between title and color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want what immediately precedes `color=red`? Then use

```
.*title=(.*?) color=red
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sR4kN2/1

This greedily matches everything that comes before `color=red`, so that only the desired title appears.

---

Alternatively, if you know there is a character that doesn't appear in the title, you can simplify by just using a character class exclusion. For example, if you know `=` won't appear:

```
title=([^=]*?) color=red
```

Or, if you know whitespace won't appear:

```
title=([^\s]*?) color=red
```

---

A third option, using a bit of code to find all red titles (assuming that the input always alternates title, color):

```
for title, color in re.findall(r'title=(.*?) color=(.*?)\( |$\)'):
    if color == 'red':
        print title
```

Comment: what if there are multiple "title=xxxx" color=red, this pattern only got the last one?

Comment: Then use the second part.

Comment: option 2 is exactly what I want, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the last match of a sub-regexp before a certain regexp the solution is to use a greedy skipper. For example:

```
>>> pattern = '.*title="([^"]*)".*color="#123"'
>>> text = 'title="123" color="#456" title="789" color="#123"'
>>> print(re.match(pattern, s).groups(1))
```

the first `.*` is greedy and it will skip as much as possible (thus skipping first `title`) backing up to the one that allows matching the desired color.

As a simpler example consider that

```
a(.*)b(.*)c
```

processed on

```
a1111b2222b3333c
```

will match `1111b2222` in the first group and `3333` in the second.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you skip the regexes, and use some split functionality instead:

```
search_title = False
found = None
string = "title=abcd color=green title=efgh color=blue title=xyxyx color=yellow title=whatIwaht colo\
r=red title=xxxy red=anything title=xxxyyy color=red"
parts = string.split()
for part in parts:
    key, value = part.split('=', 1)
    if search_title:
        if key == 'title':
            found = value
        search_title = False
    if key == 'color' and value == 'red':
        search_title = True
print(found)
```

results in

```
xxxy
```

Regexes are nice, but can cause headaches at times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [re](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) module

```
>>>string = 'title=abcd color=green title=efgh color=blue title=xyxyx color=yellow title=whatIwaht color=red'
>>>import re
>>>re.search('(.*title=?)(.*) color=red', string).group(2)
'whatIwaht'

>>>re.search('(.*title=?)(.*) color=red', string).group(2)
'xyxyx'
```